# Sending information stored in html5 localStorage via email in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Does anyone know of a way that I can get the information I have stored in html5 localStorage to populate into an email using the email composer plugin for phonegap, or any other way to do this?

Overall picture is that I am writing an ios application using phonegap and I have some information stored in localStorage which has come from a simple form. I need to get this information off the ios device and the simplest way I thought of would be to try and send this information out via e-mail.

As for as I can tell the simplest way to send email with phonegap is through a plugin called email composer, all this does is let you create a button or link which will activate the built in send email function of ios and when you send return you to the app without exiting at any point.

I am happy using html5, javascript, jquery, and css.

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Kev

Answer (score 1):

Emailcomposer has a declaration for function:

```
EmailComposer.prototype.showEmailComposer = 
function(subject,body,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,bIsHTML)
```

So, I assume (not sure since I've used it without pre-composing mail) that by calling that function with those parameters you should be able to pre-compose e-mail with your localStorage content.

.

Comment: Do you know where I can find more information on this or any examples?